# an alternative for getAllEntriesByKey?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, ssjs

I want to build a type-ahead function but I need an alternative to getAllEntriesByKey method because the initial data collection is seems to be too large for an acceptable performance.

I would rather like to use the getEntryByKey method and the next X number of documents in a View.

Is something possible? Just jump into a position in a view (matching a specified query) and collect the next X number of documents?

For now I have written most in SSJS.

Comment: Just a tip: providing only first X values may be a problem - user can't choose anything following that and/or has no info about exact number of all results. Think about the way he can choose anything beyond type ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a combination of NotesView.GetEntryByKey and NotesView.CreateViewNavFrom. This means however you will access the view twice so I do not know if you gain any performance improvement here.

An example (LotusScript) can be found here:

http://lpar.ath0.com/2011/09/19/notesviewentrycollection-vs-notesviewnavigator/

The LotusScript can easily be transformed into SSJS. I have used it something similar before. I can write a blog-post about it.